# How to get all array values in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I've been trying to create new pages using a template with some strings in it replaced by values from some arrays. The page creation working fine for specific array number. However, i'm expecting to create new pages from all values from the arrays, not just only one or two specific value.

This is the code so far:

```
<?php

 $dom= file_get_html($url);
 $array_title = array();
 $array_details = array();
 foreach ($dom->find('div[class=main]') as $results) {
        foreach ($results->find('title') as $title) {
        $array_title[] = $title->alt;
        }

        foreach ($results->find('div[class=details]') as $details) {
        $array_descript[]= $details->innertext;
        }
 }
 {
    $page = str_replace("{title}", $array_title[3], $template);
    $page = str_replace("{descript}", $array_descript[3], $page);


     //create a name for the new page
    $pagename =  $array_title[3].".php"; 

    //put the created content to file
    file_put_contents("article/".$pagename,$page);
 }

?>
```

The arrays when echoed:

```
 Array
 (
  [0] => Guacamole 
  [1] => Buffalo Chicken Dip
  [2] => Jalapeno Popper Spread
  [3] => Seven Layer Taco Dip
  [4] => Brown Sugar Smokies
  [5] => Baked Kale Chips

)

Array
(
 [0] => Guacamole recipe
 [1] => Buffalo Chicken Dip recipe
 [2] => Jalapeno Popper Spread recipe
 [3] => Seven Layer Taco Dip recipe
 [4] => Brown Sugar Smokies recipe
 [5] => Baked Kale Chips recipe
 )
```

The code above created a new page with the values in the 3rd row from the arrays. I've tried the to make the array number blank like this `[ ]`, but it returned this following error: `PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use [ ] for reading`.

May i get some insight to get all array values as i'm expecting?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Post  your array structure

Comment: You can't set `$array_title[3]` to `$array_title[]` as you are specifically selecting the 3rd element of the array and leaving it blank will throw the error you are seeing. You'd need a for loop to get all elements from `$array_title` but without knowing the structure, like @Uchiha asked for, this is hard to debug.

Comment: Arrays always start from 0, if your trying to get the 3rd result you need to do $array_title[2];

Comment: Hi @Uchiha, i just posted the array structure, thanks

Comment: @the_pete can you show me how to make the for loop thing? thanks!

Comment: Have you tried changing your code where you have $array_title[] = $title->alt; to $array_title[] = (string)$title->alt; to ensure you are adding the value as a string

Comment: hi @DannyBroadbent, i just did it. Changing to $array_title[] = $title->alt and so on. But it just created the a new page from the last value of arrays. And added three duplicated row with the same value of the last one. Am i missing something?

Comment: Whats the source of the DOM you are getting, does it have duplicated results? what is the array looking like with the new change

Comment: `the array number blank like this [ ]` -> `myarray[] = value;` is similar to `array_push(myarray, value);` You can't read `myarray[]` ...

Comment: @DannyBroadbent  i'm using `simpe_html_dom` to parse the data from some recipes site. It does make three rows duplication of the last value with the changed code you're suggested

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant, alright. So can you give me another way  to get all the values from the arrays beside that `[ ]` method? Thanks!

Comment: @purpleliciouss from the suggested change it shouldn't cause duplication, does the source of the page your putting into DOM have this last recipe duplicated on the page at all, or are you able to share the link to the one your putting into DOM. Does the change also stop that error from occurring?

Comment: @DannyBroadbent The source doesn't have the duplication of the last recipe. The arrays have no duplication before, i changed it to ` $array_title[] = $title->alt` then it got duplicated. The change does stop the error from occuring though

Comment: Just to clarify it is this part of the code you are changing: foreach ($results->find('title') as $title) {
        $array_title[] = $title->alt;
        }

Comment: @DannyBroadbent, Ok, can you please post a new answer with your modified code of my code i'm using now? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Heres your code as above with the changes I am suggesting to you:

```
<?php

 $dom= file_get_html($url);
 $array_title = array();
 $array_details = array();
 foreach ($dom->find('div[class=main]') as $results) {
        foreach ($results->find('title') as $title) {
        $array_title[] = (string)$title->alt;
        }

        foreach ($results->find('div[class=details]') as $details) {
        $array_descript[]= (string)$details->innertext;
        }
 }
 {
    $page = str_replace("{title}", $array_title[3], $template);
    $page = str_replace("{descript}", $array_descript[3], $page);


     //create a name for the new page
    $pagename =  $array_title[3].".php"; 

    //put the created content to file
    file_put_contents("article/".$pagename,$page);
 }

?>
```

Comment: Thank you! I just tried it and it seems like the page creating didn't work and all the arrays values returned blank. However, thank you for your response Danny :)